# "Transitive" uses of puer?

Tags: grammaire

I suppose this question is somewhat idle, so please don't respond from any other motive than interest, but I wonder whether native French speakers would analyse the sentence as I have done. Please consider this sentence:

> Pendant un moment, la place pua le diesel et puis ça s’estompa

Both my bilingual dictionary (Collins Robert) and my monolingual dictionary (Le Robert Dixel) have *puer* as both transitive and intransitive. Le Robert Dixel cites *Puer le sueur*, and Collins Robert cites *Ça pue l'argent* as examples of transitive usage. Regarding the sentence on which I've focussed I think it's fairly clear that both dictionaries would class *pua* as transitive and *le diesel* as a direct object.

To me this seems misguided. The subject is inanimate, *la place*, so surely *pua* must be intransitive and *le diesel* must be an adverbial.

Do people agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Puer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/puer)* is intransitive. There is never an object that is *pué* by the subject (the past participle doesn't even exist).

*Le diesel* is nevertheless a complement that specify what odor it is about. It somewhat looks like a *complément attributif*.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I too prefer to consider puer as intransitive, but I note that wordreference.com is another dictionary that considers that it can also be transitive. I find the differences of opinion curious. On your second point, I like to think of complements as necessary components of a predicate, and adverbials as (grammatically) optional.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with the past participle itself. It can be used in active voice compound tenses.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez That's right. My point was about the fact we don't read or hear *le diesel est pué par la place*.

Answer (score 0):

*X pue Y* means that X smells Y.
Whether X is inanimate or not makes no difference. X is the object/person/whatever that smells and Y is the smell.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I agree with your final sentence but it doesn't really address the issue of transitivity and the grammatical role of le diesel within the sentence.